# Vala. How to connect SQLite in Anjuta IDE?

Tags: sqlite, vala, anjuta

In line

```
using Sqlite;
```

an error occurs: "The namespace name` Sqlite 'could not be found "

I previously installed SQLite and command line compilation works :

```
valac --pkg gtk + -3.0 --pkg sqlite3 -X -lm SomeFile.vala
```

But if I create and compile a project in Anjuta, then an error occurs

Comment: I just want to add that now the best experience of vala development is Visual Studio + this VLS. https://github.com/philippejer/vala-language-client-alpha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use VS Code with VLS and Builder, but I think the same is true for Anjuta(is this IDE still alive?) For correct operation Vala Language Server all dependencies should be described in the Build file Meson. For the Vala Language Server to work correctly, all the dependencies must be described in the Meson Build file.

Here is an example that I use with the plugin for VS Code:

```
project('vala app', 'vala', 'c')

dependencies = [
    dependency('glib-2.0'),
    dependency('gobject-2.0'),
    dependency('sqlite3'),
    dependency('gee-0.8'),

]

sources = files('valite.vala')

executable('valite', sources, dependencies: dependencies, install: true)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Now instead of Anjuta, I use VS Code for editing and debugging, and Meson + Ninja for compilation